Can this be considered as self-plagiarism?
I started working on a paper using method A, aiming to reach conclusion B. However, method A proved to be not so great and did not yield the expected results. That's fine, and as a result, the paper's focus shifted to a comparison of method A with a much more recent method A*. Unfortunately, this change meant we couldn't reach conclusion B. Instead, the paper became more technical and consists of a comparison with some partial conclusions.
I then started another paper using only method A*, where the accuracy of the method is less of a concern. I wrote this paper reaching conclusion B and beyond. Method A is not mentioned in this paper, BUT:

The methods used are fairly similar in their conception (different techniques, same branches), but diverge later on to reach conclusion B.
Some aspects of the papers are similar (same graphs for both papers but using different methods, ~2 out of 10 graphs).

Overall, the aim and conception of the papers are vastly different (one is a technical comparison, and the other aims to be impactful for experimentalists), but I am still concerned that it might be flagged as self-plagiarism on some points.
EDIT: also something important: this meant that I had to "hold" some information that could be put in the first paper for the second one.
I have a feeling that this situation might be more common than I initially thought. What is expected in this case? I would prefer not to merge the two papers since it would add confusion and break the narrative of both of them.

Was the first paper published? Has the second paper been published already?

Assuming that the first paper has been published and the second is in preparation, it is simple enough to cite the first paper in the second, saying that the new methodology is a variation/extension of the older one is sufficient to avoid charges of plagiarism and self plagiarism.
Make the full context clear and there are no issues.
If the second paper has already been published then you might try to request an update from the editor. Even a note on their website might be a successful dodge. But, yes, using something of your own without citation is a form of self plagiarism. It potentially denies readers of the full context of ideas and their origin.
If the first paper is still in preparation then there are more possibilities.

None of the papers have been published, the first one is going to be submitted very soon, the second one is still in the work. Simply citing in this case is enough then?

Yes, citation is how you avoid all sorts of plagiarism. Make the source of ideas clear to the reader.
